# Выбор браузера и перехват cookie

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Какую библиотеку лучше всего использовать для инициализации браузера с последующим перехватом cookies и их модификации(а также сохранении в json)? Стандартный Webrequest или лучше CefSharp? Можно примеры реализации подобной задачи)

Грубо говоря мне нужно вставить браузер в WinForms, авторизоваться вручную, затем идет тело программы без использования визуализации.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А в чём вы видите недостатки одного или другого? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: @VladD _"А в чём вы видите недостатки одного или другого?"_ -- мне кажется что тут как "Витязь на распутье". ТС еще не ходил ни по одной из дорог. поэтому спрашивает какую лучше выбрать.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

var f = new Form();
var b = new WebBrowser() { Parent=f, Dock=DockStyle.Fill, ScriptErrorsSuppressed=true };
b.Navigated += delegate { 
   // вывести полученные cookie
   Console.WriteLine(b.Document != null ? b.Document.Cookie : "null"); 
};
b.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com");
f.ShowDialog();
```